# Restore deleted auto-renewable subscription

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

How does it look like when you delete the auto-renewal subscription from iTunes Connect for your app, and your user will do restore (and have bought some auto-renewal sub in the past)?

Example scenario:

1. User purchases auto-renewable subscription and he is subscribed for some time.
2. I delete auto-renewable subscription in iTunes Connect (user subscription is cancelled).
3. User e.g. uninstalls app and install it again and do restore.

Will he get all the transactions associated with deleted subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Important: After you delete an In-App Purchase, it is no longer
>   searchable on iTunes Connect and it cannot be restored. The product ID
>   for the In-App Purchase can no longer be used for another In-App
>   Purchase after the In-App Purchase is deleted.

[At the very bottom of iTunes Connect Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide.pdf)